Delphi 10.2 Tokyo + Oracle 11g "'Cannot load oci.dll library (error code 126)", only on DEBUG mode. (ADO Connection or DBX TSQL Connection)
I'm facing a big problem with those two technologies above, I used to have a 32bit operational system Windows 10, with the same technology and it was working just fine. Still, the machine went AWOL and started to show infinite BSODS and I couldn't repair it, I have to replace it, since 32-bit only takes 3GB RAM, and I want to upgrade for it to have better performance.
Now I've migrated to Windows 10-64bit and started to have an error only on Debug mode and I can't seem to pass that or debug anything anymore.

I can build and compile, normally;
I can play the compiled app on the same machine and the error does not present itself (also on F8-Run Without Debugging, it works just fine);

But when I try to debug in F9, those errors below start to happen:
Project app.exe raised the exception class TDBXError with the message 'Cannot load oci.dll library (error code 126).  The oci.dll library may be missing from the system path or you may have an incompatible version of the library installed'.
Project app.exe raised exception class EOleException with the message 'Cannot load oci.dll library (error code 126).  The oci.dll library may be missing from the system path or you may have an incompatible version of the library installed'.
My app is a 32-based application.
Does anybody have any idea if this is fixable, because I have been searching for days topics around this and tried a bunch of everything and I didn't get anywhere;

Try to install ORACLE client;
Put DLLs in windows system folder;
Try to install ODAC;

I want/need to be able to Debug the application;

If that is a Windows error (and not Oracle or Delphi) then it could be $8007007e which is ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND: The specified module could not be found. Are you sure your oci.dll even exists as 32 bit version? Use Process Explorer to see where the (normally) loaded DLL actually resides and how Delphi could be unable to locate that.

In debug mode some exceptions are exposed that would be handled in code - like loading something from another location. What  happens when you Ignore the exception?

Note oci.dll is part of the Oracle database client. One version of the Oracle instant client is a bunch of files you can place in the directory of the progarm that wants to use it. No install neccessary.

You say that you put DLL's in Windows System folder. Which System folder? On 64 bit Windows Windows\System32 folder actually contains 64 bit programs and dynamic libraries. In order to make some dynamic library accessible by 32 bit application you should use Windows\SysWOW64 folder instead. When looking for Dynamic libraries all 32 bit applications are redirected to it. Don't ask me why Microsoft made such counter intuitive decision. You can read more about this at File System Redirector

@AmigoJack, I did, but really i couldn't find where Embarcadero Rad Studio was getting the DLL from;

@Brian
Understood, thanks for the Help;

@SilverWarior Understood, that's very weird, but it is what it is; Microsoft sometimes doesn't make much sense in some decisions.

I fix this problem, this is how:

Format the machine, start the process again, 2 things I did:
. Install ODAC 11GB client side, from Oracle website;
. Install Oracle 11G server side in the same machine that I have the DevTools enviroment with the same password and same database as the server oracle.

The second step is what I think that put the necessary DLL's need to run Debug. I just didn't understand very well what happen, but it worked. Thanks everybody for the help!!
